# how to create jwt token in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt

I get this error:

> System.Text.Json.JsonException: A possible object cycle was detected which is not supported. This can either be due to a cycle or if the object depth is larger than the maximum allowed depth of 32.

My code:

```
public string GeneratJwt(Users users, List<UserRoles> roles)
{
            var secretKey = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("NewSecurity123456");
            var signingCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(secretKey), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature);

            var claims = _getClaims(users, roles);

            var descriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
            {
                Issuer = "MyApi",
                Audience = "OnlineStorePerfume",
                IssuedAt = DateTime.Now,
                NotBefore = DateTime.Now,
                Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(3),
                SigningCredentials = signingCredentials,
                Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(claims)
            };

            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var secretToken = tokenHandler.CreateToken(descriptor);

            var jwt = tokenHandler.WriteToken(secretToken);
            return jwt;
}

private IEnumerable<Claim> _getClaims(Users users, List<UserRoles> roles)
{
            var list = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, users.UserName),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, users.UserId.ToString()),
            };

            foreach (var item in roles)
            {
                list.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, item.Role.RoleTitle));
            }

            return list;
}
```

Comment: I don't think that is caused from creating token function ,can you please check where cause the circular references with JSON ?

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (var item in roles)
{
     list.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, item.Role.RoleTitle));
}
```

On the code above, you are adding many claims with the same type (ClaimTypes.Role) and the json serializer is failling to serialize it.